# How to restore the Unity login screen after installing Xubuntu desktop in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, xubuntu, xfce

I have just installed an Xubuntu desktop on my Ubuntu Unity 14.04 system using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop gksu leafpad synaptic
```

from [this](http://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/alternative) site:

After logging out and logging into an "Xubuntu session" and running this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove nautilus gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver gnome-termina* gnome-pane* gnome-applet* gnome-bluetooth gnome-desktop* gnome-sessio* gnome-user* gnome-shell-common compiz compiz* unity unity* hud zeitgeist zeitgeist* python-zeitgeist libzeitgeist* activity-log-manager-common gnome-control-center gnome-screenshot overlay-scrollba* && sudo apt-get install xubuntu-community-wallpapers && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and when restarting I come to a Xubuntu login window, and when I click on the little Xubuntu icon at the top righthand corner I can only run an "Xfce session" or an "Xubuntu session".

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Thanks that is what I've done, logged out.(from terminal because the clicky thing didn't work)                                      Logged into an "Ubuntu session" And now...   Ubuntu looks wrong??? Any ideas.

Comment: "ubuntu looks wrong" , what exactly do you mean by that ?

Comment: Some of the icons are Xubuntu ones and the exit, minimise and maximise buttons aren't in a circle. Hope that helps

Comment: Install unity tweak tool through Ubuntu software center or 'sudo apt-get intall unity-tweak-tool'. In the main menu there will be four fields - unity , window manager, appearance, and system. Under appearance there is Icons menu. Click on that and there should be available list of icons from bunch of themes. Basically, with this tool you can have one theme, but use another set of icons. Just look through those, which one suits you best. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Will do I'll get back to you soon!

Comment: THANKS ALOT!!!!!  Everything works and looks fine and I can even customise Unity

Comment: ^_0 No problem, enjoy.

Answer (score 4):

re install lightdm 
in the login form type alt+ctrl+f1

```
$ sudo service lightdm stop
$ sudo apt-get remove lightdm
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install lightdm
$ sudo service lightdm start 
$ sudo service lightdm restart
```

the alt+ctrl+f7

Comment: Thank you! Using 16.04 here. lightdm was broken after I installed `kubuntu-desktop`. No launcher and no dash. This is the *only* thing that fixed it after checking a zillion pages and pulling my hair out for hours!! I did have to reboot as well but this is what fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

Uninstalling the entire Ubuntu desktop and reinstalling might fix the problem and it might not. Whatever the process is long and can be messy. Here's a simple way to switch back to the default Ubuntu desktop after installing Xubuntu, Kubuntu, Ubuntustudio, or any other desktop that also uses lightdm.

Open a terminal and execute the following commands:

```
echo '[SeatDefaults]' | sudo tee /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf
echo 'greeter-session=unity-greeter' | sudo tee -a /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf
sudo chmod +x /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf
```

Reboot or restart lightdm for the changes to take effect. [For an explanation of why this works click here.](https://askubuntu.com/a/500040/167115)

Comment: Worked perfectly for Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks!!