# Ubuntu to Xubuntu Dual Boot

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, xubuntu, games, crash

Well, Ubuntu keeps crashing and from what I've seen Xubuntu has never crashed on me.  So I want to put the Xubuntu Desktop Environment over Ubuntu.  (It's unity that keeps crashing)  However, I want to play games on this computer through Wine and Steam.  I also want Xubuntu because it will play games more quick considering Xubuntu has a lesser 3D graphical interface.

Can I install the Desktop over Ubuntu or will I have to grab a Xubuntu disk and overwrite Ubuntu 14.04?

All feedback is appreciated and I look forward to your answers.  And here is the exact error I get.

```
Sorry, Ubuntu 14.04 has experienced an internal error.

Path
-/usr/share/unity-scopes/scope-runner-dbus.py
(And yes, I have reinstalled this.  But it still crashes.
ProblemType
-Crash
Title
-scope-runner-dbus.py crashed with SIGSEGV in ffl_call_unix64()
Architecture
-amd64
```

Comment: For an answer to your second question see: [How do I switch to Xubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/64241/how-do-i-switch-to-xubuntu).

Comment: Well I figured out how to use Wine in Xubuntu so I'm good there.  And I'm waiting for my updates to get done to see if I can use that tool.  That is for 11.04.  Will it work for 14.04 as well?  Thanks. :)

Comment: There is the same xubuntu-desktop package in 14.04 as well as lightdm, so it should also work in Ubuntu 14.04. According to this question: [How to restore the Unity login screen after installing Xubuntu desktop in Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/492605/how-to-restore-the-unity-login-screen-after-installing-xubuntu-desktop-in-ubuntu) it can be done in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Alright, now I'm just waiting to get done with the installation. Thanks and I'll see how Steam turns out. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No dual boot needed. Xubuntu is just ubuntu with XFCE desktop. Install `xubuntu-desktop` package using `sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop`. And choose XFCE as your session on greeter.